# Max wallet is not implementing on transfer function

Tags: solidity, tokens, smart-contract-wallets

Transfer is working however max wallet limits are not applying.
This is not the entire function, take fee part is next but I'm quite sure this is where the error lies.

```
    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override {

    require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
    require(amount > 0, "amount must be greater than 0");
               

        if (from != owner() && to != owner() && to != address(0) && to != address(0xdead)){
            if(!tradingActive){
                require(_isExcludedFromFees[from] || _isExcludedFromFees[to], "Trading is not active.");
            }
                        
            //when buy
            if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] && !_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[to]) {

                    require((balanceOf(to) + amount) <= maxWallet, "Cannot Exceed max wallet");
            } 
            //when sell
            else if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && !_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[from]) {

            } 
            else if (!_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[to] && !_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[from]){
            
            }
        }
```

Comment: without additional context or information, it's difficult to determine why the max wallet limits is not working. It's possible that there is an error and max wallet limit is not being set correctly.